# Combining COUNTIFS with INDEX and MATCH for a variable date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I'm not sure if my title makes much sense, so hopefully the example below will better illustrate what I'm aiming for.

Synopsis: I have an array of 3 birds (A3:A5), and 7 sample dates (B2:H2). At each sample date, each bird picked a specific fruit to eat (or none) (B3:H5). Additionally, each bird has a specific mating season that starts on certain sample dates and ends on a later sample date (B10:C12).

I want to calculate:
**For each bird, how many of each type of fruit did they consume during their respective mating season.**

See the attached screenshot of the data. **I am hoping to calculate both the green and purple sections.** I wrote in the answers to the first column manually, but I have a large dataset where I need to use formulas to calculate.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Screenshot of data]

Answer (score 0):

As the birds are listed in the same order in rows 3:5 10:12 and 17:19 the below works:

Paste the following into cell B17 and drag the fill handle over to cell E17 and then down to cell E19: `=COUNTIFS($B3:$H3,B$16,$B$2:$H$2,">="&$B10,$B$2:$H$2,"<="&$C10)`

Paste the following into cell F17 and then drag the fill handle down to cell F19: `=SUM(B17,D17)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT function, enter the formula an drag to Right and Down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$4=$A17)*($B$2:$H$4=B16)*($B$1:$H$1>=$B10)*($B$1:$H$1<=$C10))
```

[image]

For Peach or Pear column you can use SUM function directly and drag to Down:

```
=SUM(B17,D17)
```

[image]